# How to create a total list of values from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I currently have a dict that I want to create a final total list of keys and values from:

```
adict = {'f': {'g', 'd'}, 
         'd': {'g'}, 
         'e': {'d'}, 
         'b': {'d'}, 
         'c': {'f', 'e'}, 
         'a': {'b', 'c'}}
```

I currently am looking for a function in this format:

```
def create_final_total_list(thedictionary: dict(), startingkey:str):
    final_list = []
    # function here
```

What I want is to have the user input a starting key which appends the key and its values to the final_list. And those values also become keys which will also append all their values into the final_list and so on.

Example if starting key would be 'a' then it first does:

```
 final_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then it would see 'b' and 'c' values and add their values from the dict so it would become:

```
final_list = ['a', 'b', 'c',
              'b', 'd',
              'c', 'f', 'e', ...]
```

And from values 'd', 'f' and 'e' it would become:

```
final_list = ['a', 'b', 'c',

              'b', 'd',
              'c', 'f', 'e'

              'd', 'g'
              'f', 'g', 'd'
              'e', 'd' ...]
```

and so on...

Its sort of like a reaching function, that reaches from one key and from its values, to the next.

How would I approach this in Python 3.3?

Comment: Am I right assuming that the input dict defines some oriented graph through its adjacent nodes?

Comment: This is topological sort, I guess.

Comment: @bereal Your assumption is right.

Comment: I'd imagine a recursive solution is going to come out the shortest and (depending on your worldview) simplest. Wish I had a bit of time to put one together... maybe this evening...

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

Using `deque` as your queue:

```
>>> from topsort import adict, create_final_total_list
>>> adict
{'a': {'b', 'c'}, 'b': {'d'}, 'c': {'e', 'f'}, 'd': {'g'}, 'e': {'d'}, 'f': {'d', 'g'}}
>>> create_final_total_list(adict, 'c')
['c', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'd', 'g', 'g', 'd', 'g', 'g', 'e', 'd', 'd', 'g', 'g']
```

The code for the function:

```
def create_final_total_list(the_dict, startingkey):
    final_list = []
    var = deque([startingkey])
    while var:
        u = var.pop()
        final_list.append(u)
        s = the_dict[u] if u in the_dict else None
        if s:
            final_list.extend(s)
            var.extend(s)

    return final_list
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your first dictionary so that it contains a dict of lists (else syntax was not correct), then I just passed your final list as an out parameter:

```
>>> adict = {'f': ['g', 'd'], 
         'd': ['g'], 
         'e': ['d'], 
         'b': ['d'], 
         'c': ['f', 'e'], 
         'a': ['b', 'c']}
>>> def create_final_total_list(thedictionary, startingkey, final_list):
    final_list.append(startingkey)
    final_list.extend(thedictionary[startingkey])


>>> fl = []
>>> create_final_total_list(adict, 'a', fl)
>>> fl
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> create_final_total_list(adict, 'b', fl)
>>> create_final_total_list(adict, 'c', fl)
>>> fl
['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'f', 'e']
>>>
```

Comment: `{'g', 'd'}` is valid syntax and defines a `set`

Answer (score 0):

I see a posted answer, so I will any way post mine. My Queue implementation was simple list though not sure if there would be any benefit in using queue or dqueue

**Implementation**

```
def create_final_total_list(thedictionary, key):
    final_list = list(thedictionary[key])
    Q = list(thedictionary[key])
    while Q:
        key = Q.pop(0)
        final_list+=thedictionary.get(key, [])
        Q+=thedictionary.get(key, [])
    return final_list
```

**Output**

```
>>> create_final_total_list(adict, 'a')
['c', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g']
```

Answer (score 0):

An recursive implementation could be:

```
from itertools import chain

adict = {'f': {'g', 'd'}, 
         'd': {'g'}, 
         'e': {'d'}, 
         'b': {'d'}, 
         'c': {'f', 'e'}, 
         'a': {'b', 'c'}}

def create_final_list(dict_, key):
    values = list(dict_.get(key, []))
    return [key] + values + \
        list(chain(*[create_final_list(dict_, v) for v in values]))

print create_final_list(adict, "a")
```

This prints:

```
['a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'e', 'd', 'd', 'g', 'g', 'f', 'd', 'g', 'd', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'g', 'g']
```

Please note that the order of elements in a set `{"a","b"}` is not fixed, thus the order may vary.